# github link confusiom

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, github

I tried uploading my work using angular/vs code. I think i did everything but when i run the link im getting a 404 error, but when i run it using the root folder i just get the readme file info. I tried adding index.html in the end nothing. im out of options now can anybody help me (https://andilekwazimsomi.github.io/project/)

Im out of options now as ive tried everything even creating a new repository

Comment: Have you tried building the angular project and then pushing it to the andilekwazimsomi.github.io repository?

Comment: yes i did try that

Comment: Can you show me the repository you deployed to?

Answer (score 0):

You have to build your project using `ng build` command. After that, you can upload ir to github or other hosting.

Upload directly angular project files won't work.

Here you have more information about that https://angular.io/cli/build

Comment: when do i use the command build